# MKMapView hang/freeze app after leave viewcontroller in iPhone 5c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

I have a viewcontroller where `MKMapView` is working fine, updating map based on current location. I followed [this](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/mapkit-for-user-location-in-ios) tutorial.

The Problem is when I leave the view controller the app got stuck just after call `dealloc`.

This is happening on iPhone 5c, it works fine on iPhone 6!

Comment: why are you setting delegate to `nil` in `dealloc` ?

Comment: @Lion I just discovered it works fine when I unplug iPhone from xcode.

Comment: HOLLY SHIT! I was having the same issue.... I unplugged the phone from Xcode and its working now!!! man I have been trying to debug this issue like for 3 days now and it was driving me crazy!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just discovered it works fine when I unplug iPhone from xcode.

Comment: This is so sad :(

Comment: @Shuvo Joseph, same experience with me too! nice discovery man